# What is this part in this 1956 Ford Fairlane in the picture?

Tags: ford, part-identification

I went to a junkyard and saw a 1956 Ford Fairlane with the Y-Block V8. But i couldnt understand what this part circled in yellow could be, does anybody know what this part is and what it does?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see it totally, but it looks like the blower motor for the heater. I can see the heater box behind it, which looks like it may be attached.